# How to test VisualStateManager states?

Tags: wpf, visualstatemanager

How do I check the current states of a control?  VisualStateManager allows me to set it from the control itself, but I can't see any way of reading it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have one group, or wants to find the state in a specific group you can do something like :

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Group1">
            <VisualState x:Name="State1">
                <Storyboard>

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="State2">
                <Storyboard>

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

and in your code you can do something like :

```
var state = Group1.CurrentState;
Console.WriteLine(state.Name);
```